# how to filter logs from my log file

Tags: shell, unix, sh

I have an exception file `exception.txt`, which contains all the exception lines that occurred yesterday.

Example:

```
Null pointer exception
Socket exception
Network exception
End of file exception.
```

I also have filter file `filter.txt`, which contains a few exception keywords like

```
End of file exception
Null pointer exception
```

I would like to create a `newexception.txt` file with shell script by filtering those lines that are mentioned in `filter.txt`.
Basically it should be a copy of `exception.txt` ignoring the lines from `filter.txt`.

What would be the best way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read all the lines from your filter file and form a regular expression from it:

```
lines=`cat filter.txt`
regex=${lines//$'\n'/|}
egrep -v "$regex" exception.txt
```

This will flatten the filter lines into a single string by replacing newlines with `|`, so your regex would look like `End of file exception|Null pointer exception`. This way you could also use filter key words that form regular expressions by themselves, such as `so* exception`.
Note this requires bash.

Comment: This doesn't work. I do not see any output even after giving fullpath of filter.txt and exception.txt

Comment: @chandan You need to type it in a bash shell, or add a `#!/usr/bin/bash` line if it's a script.

Comment: I did that but still not working to yield any output.

Comment: @chandan what's in the files?

Comment: file is not getting created only.

Comment: It worked as newexception.txt was missing. lines=`cat filter.txt`
regex=${lines//$'\n'/|}
egrep -v "$regex" exception.txt > newexception.txt

Answer (score 1):

If you know what keywords you have on filter.txt. The easiest and maybe the fastest way is grep, using -v option.

```
grep -v -e 'keyword1' -e 'keyword2' exception.txt
```